# Can't start express app on Windows 7/64bit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have installed node for windows/64bit and I can run server with example form node homepage(node is working). But when I setup express app it's not able to start server. Express is install with `npm install -g express` command, and `express test`, `npm install` commands instal all necessary files but when I type `node app.js` in cmd it just skippes line. All `path` variables are setup and everything is working exept this.

Comment: No issue with that here.  You haven't provided enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it just skips line"? Also, can you post the source of the app.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of runnig `node app.js` try `npm start`.

express generator now put file to start the server in `bin/www` so you have to say `node bin/www` to start the app.

If you will see your `package.json` you will get something like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
}
```

so to start the server you can say `npm start` or `node bin/www`.

Comment: Can u eleborate a bit plz, what I'm supouse to do?